# ansibl inventory : create temporary inventory with multiple groups with add_host or group_by

Tags: ansible, vsphere

I have an assignment to provision {{ create new hosts }} according to a given 
invonteroy file,
example

```
[SET1]
1.1.1.1 new_ip=1.1.1.1

[SET2]
1.1.1.2 new_ip=1.1.1.2

[SET3]
1.1.1.3 new_ip=1.1.1.3
```

Here is the problem. The inventory file contains set of ip addresses that do not exists yet.
What I want to do

```
- connect to vsphere host(5.5)
- create new machines based on amount of hosts in the inventory
- change the machines ip address to match the one in the given inventory
```

modules like

```
vmware_shell
vmware_guest
```

requires administrative permissions which I don't have.
The only way to hack around this issue is to try and create an in memory or temporary inventory during provisioning  task.
Here is my role:

```
- vsphere_guest:
    vcenter_hostname: {{ vcenter }}
    validate_certs: no
    username: "{{ vsphere.username }}"
    password: "{{ vsphere.password }}"
    guest: "{{ item }}"
    from_template: yes
    template_src: Centos_base
    resource_pool: "/Resources"
    esxi:
      datacenter: Remote
      hostname: {{ esx_host }}
  with_items:
      - "{{ play_hosts }}"

- name: wait for power on to finish
  pause: seconds=5

- name: get facts from vm
  vsphere_guest:
    validate_certs: False
    vcenter_hostname: {{ vcenter }} 
    username:  "{{ vsphere.username }}"
    password:  "{{ vsphere.password }}"
    guest: "{{ item  }}"
    vmware_guest_facts: yes
  with_items:
      - "{{ play_hosts }}"
  register: vm_facts
  until: vm_facts.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0] is defined
  retries: 10
  delay: 10

- name: grab new ipaddresses
  set_fact: myIp="{{ inventory_hostname }}"

- name: Add production VMs to inventory
  add_host: hostname={{item.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0] }} groups=temp
            new_ip={{ myIp }}
  with_items: "{{ vm_facts.results }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

my question:
is there any way to create a temp inventory with multiple groups and mutilple variables that matches the given inventory!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update
I hacked a way around it:

```
- name: Add production VMs to inventory
  add_host: hostname={{item.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0] }} groups=temp
            new_ip="{{ item.ansible_facts.hw_name }}"
  with_items: "{{ vm_facts.results }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

this works since the machine name is equal to {{ play_host }}